# how to get text of kendo editor text in button click

Tags: editor

I am using Kendo UI editor for my project (MVC 4 application).

In the button click event I need to display the editor text in another div once user enters the text and clicks on the preview button.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getClick(e) {

        try {             //the name of your editor
            var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
            var editorContent = editor.value();
            alert(editorContent);
            //Do Your stuff here 

        }
        catch (e) { }
    }
```

then call with a button

```
 <button class="k-button" id="btnPreviewContent" onclick="getClick()">PreviewEditor Content</button>
```

Comment: when I try this I only get the marked up text. Is there a way to get all the html tags as well?